# Spring boot, Thymeleaf how do I get language parameter from webpage

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am developing a multi-language web app using Spring-boot. I have to get the current language of the web UI. id=s there any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind to get the Locale is this:

```java
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

If you want to set the Locale you can use this:

```java
setLocale(Locale locale);
```

For further information you can look here [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html).

Comment: If this solved your problem don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

use for current language:

```
${#locale.language}
```

use for current country:

```
${#locale.country}
```